# Error when I Migrate my project to androidx?

Tags: java, android

[My project](https://github.com/CPPAlien/FileTransfer)

[Main class](https://github.com/CPPAlien/FileTransfer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/pengtao/filetransfer/MainActivity.java)

I successfully migrated my project to androidx .

after I build my project it occurs an error in build folder.

[error at build folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfJhg.png)

Error :

`D:\jp\ft\FileTransfer\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out\me\pengtao\filetransfer\MainActivity_ViewBinding.java:4: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.CallSuper;
^
D:\jp\ft\FileTransfer\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out\me\pengtao\filetransfer\MainActivity_ViewBinding.java:5: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.UiThread;
^

D:\jp\ft\FileTransfer\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out\me\pengtao\filetransfer\PopupMenuDialog_ViewBinding.java:4: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.CallSuper;
^
D:\jp\ft\FileTransfer\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out\me\pengtao\filetransfer\PopupMenuDialog_ViewBinding.java:5: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.UiThread;
^
D:\jp\ft\FileTransfer\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out\me\pengtao\filetransfer\MainActivity_ViewBinding.j
ava:22: error: cannot find symbol
@UiThread
^
symbol:   class UiThread
location: class MainActivity_ViewBinding
where T is a type-variable:
T extends MainActivity declared in class MainActivity_ViewBinding

D:\jp\ft\FileTransfer\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out\me\pengtao\filetransfer\MainActivity_ViewBinding.j
`
ava:42: error: cannot find symbol
@CallSuper
^
symbol:   class CallSuper
location: class MainActivity_ViewBinding
where T is a type-variable:
T extends MainActivity declared in class MainActivity_ViewBinding

D:\jp\ft\FileTransfer\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out\me\pengtao\filetransfer\PopupMenuDialog_ViewBin
ding.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
@UiThread
^
symbol:   class UiThread
location: class PopupMenuDialog_ViewBinding
where T is a type-variable:
T extends PopupMenuDialog declared in class PopupMenuDialog_ViewBinding

```
   D:\jp\ft\FileTransfer\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out\me\pengtao\filetransfer\PopupMen 
   uDialog_ViewBinding.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
   @CallSuper
   ^
   symbol:   class CallSuper
   location: class PopupMenuDialog_ViewBinding<T>
   where T is a type-variable:
   T extends PopupMenuDialog declared in class PopupMenuDialog_ViewBinding
    8 errors

   > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    *   Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log 
    output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 3m 33s
    17 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 8 up-to-date
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: you where using android.support.annotation in MainActivity class, check imports

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project , if error still exists then please add you MainActivity class and layout file to the question .

Answer (score 2):

AndroidX and Butterknife only works with 9.0.0-SNAPSHOT or later

you can update your define in build.gradle as below

```
    butterknife        : "com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1",
    butterknifeCompiler: "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1",
```

Comment: I will check this.